# Create a colormap with white centered around zero

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I must admit, understanding how to create or manipulate matplotlib's colormaps is not an easy thing. Therefore I'm seeking a little help in explaining and setting up a colormap that goes from blue (negative) to red (positive) and has white centered tightly around zero. I would then like to use this cmap in `contourf`:

1. This works but the colors are reversed

   ```
   cs = plt.contourf(longrid, latgrid,
                     ar[window-1]-bkgrd, levels,
                     cmap = cm.get_cmap('BuRd', len(levels)-1))
   ```
2. The problem here is that `BuRd_r` takes away the white around zero

   ```
   cs = plt.contourf(longrid, latgrid,
                     ar[window-1]-bkgrd, levels,
                     cmap = cm.get_cmap('BuRd_r', len(levels)-1))
   ```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Here's the function and data to test the colormap:

```
def PlotAnomalyCF(ar,hgrid,latgrid,longrid,outfile,levels,units):                        
    window = 1                                                                           
    tsize = 8                                                                            
    plt.close()                                                                          
    plt.figure(figsize=(11.7,4.3) )                                                      
    plt.clf()                                                                            
    plt.cla()                                                                            

    bkgrd = bn.nanmean(ar[:],0)

    for v in hgrid:OA                                                                    
        plt.subplot(1,len(hgrid),window)                                                 
        plt.title(v,fontsize=tsize)                                                      
        plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.07,bottom=0.75,                                       
                            right=0.98, top=0.92,                                        
                            wspace=0.12,hspace=0.98)                                     
        cs = plt.contourf(longrid,latgrid,                                               
                          ar[window-1]-bkgrd,levels,                                     
                          cmap=cm.get_cmap('BuRd_r',len(levels)-1))                      
        cs.cmap.set_over('r')                                                            
        plt.grid(True)                                                                   
        plt.axis('off')                                                                  
        window += 1                                                                      
    ax = plt.gca()                                                                       
    pos = ax.get_position()                                                              
    l,b,w,h = pos.bounds                                                                 
    print l,b,w,h                                                                        
    cax = plt.axes([l-0.848,b-0.05,0.91,0.02]) # setup colorbar axes                     
    cbar = plt.colorbar(cs,cax=cax,orientation='horizontal')                             
    cl = plt.getp(cbar.ax, 'xticklabels')                                                
    plt.setp(cl, fontsize=8)
    # Add units text                                                                     
    plt.figtext(0.012,0.83,units,fontsize=tsize+1)                                       
    print 'outfile.',outfile                                                             
    plt.savefig(outfile,dpi=900,orientation='landscape',format='pdf')                    
    plt.show()

# Data
hgrid = array([-18, -15, -12,  -9,  -6,  -3,   0,   3,   6,   9,  12,  15,  18])
latgrid = array([ 5.61402391,  4.91227095,  4.21051798,  3.508765  ,  2.80701201,
                  2.10525902,  1.40350602,  0.70175301,  0.        , -0.70175302,
                 -1.40350604, -2.10525907, -2.8070121 , -3.50876514, -4.21051818,
                 -4.91227122, -5.61402427])
longrid = array([-5.625   , -4.921875, -4.21875 , -3.515625, -2.8125  , -2.109375,
                 -1.40625 , -0.703125,  0.      ,  0.703125,  1.40625 ,  2.109375,
                 2.8125  ,  3.515625,  4.21875 ,  4.921875,  5.625   ])
levels = array([-20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10,  -9,  -8,
                -7,  -6,  -5,  -4,  -3,  -2,  -1,   0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,
                 6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,
                 19,  20])
units ='$\mathrm{CC_{200}\,[\%]}$'
ar = shape is (13, 17, 17) with max = 82.4 and min = 45.5. It would be easier to just
     generate some random data within these intervals. Alternatively just copy one of the 
     array:
ar[1] = array([[ 46.91224792,  46.21374984,  46.86130719,  47.01021234,
     46.72626813,  46.2288305 ,  46.43835451,  45.79325437,
     45.58271668,  46.35872217,  48.08725987,  48.44553638,
     47.76519316,  47.6366742 ,  48.40425078,  48.77756577,
     49.33566712],
   [ 46.83599932,  46.84286989,  47.33453309,  46.55030976,
     46.80566458,  46.53292035,  47.02261763,  47.41084421,
     47.38724565,  47.91122826,  49.21117552,  49.45223641,
     49.97629913,  50.44165439,  51.08080398,  50.79600723,  49.968034  ],
   [ 47.42288313,  47.07674124,  46.7167639 ,  46.11959218,
     46.95814111,  46.88763807,  47.79510368,  48.50213272,
     49.14340301,  50.0550682 ,  50.96554707,  51.70960776,
     52.76304827,  53.13428506,  53.01955687,  52.57951586,
     51.91245273],
   [ 47.71067291,  47.48154219,  47.40131211,  47.45929857,
     48.46118424,  48.65199823,  49.38156691,  49.86137507,
     50.55394084,  51.96604309,  52.60579898,  53.69096203,
     54.22750101,  54.37757099,  54.31517398,  53.47697773,
     53.41809044],
   [ 48.20779565,  48.58856851,  48.75880829,  49.40822878,
     50.03355014,  51.44922083,  52.00567831,  52.99485667,
     53.69339127,  53.58208129,  53.88588998,  55.24096208,
     55.24137628,  55.38338399,  55.30856415,  55.0329081 ,
     54.58041914],
   [ 49.20063728,  49.81223264,  50.2145489 ,  50.54749112,
     51.44252761,  53.1708726 ,  54.48141824,  55.1337493 ,
     55.86338227,  55.80719304,  56.1060897 ,  56.15050406,
     56.10404113,  56.82550383,  57.12370494,  56.79250814,
     57.21656741],
   [ 50.17222332,  50.78494993,  51.47036476,  51.78513471,
     54.07329312,  55.12136894,  56.63202678,  56.77587861,
     57.60688855,  57.31874243,  57.86532727,  58.38753463,
     58.52204736,  58.8451274 ,  59.17282185,  58.93137673,
     58.90977463],
   [ 51.50642331,  51.51055372,  52.44746806,  53.37696513,
     54.86775802,  56.68992167,  57.90624404,  58.76394172,
     59.64662899,  59.80540837,  59.98355254,  60.05761821,
     59.95848562,  60.54540623,  60.4776266 ,  60.11749116,
     59.74209418],
   [ 51.40396463,  51.48043239,  52.89530187,  53.73500868,
     55.39612502,  56.70178532,  58.07064267,  59.56644298,
     60.47288049,  60.59095081,  61.26474813,  61.20278944,
     61.43807574,  61.1942828 ,  60.40014922,  59.78371327,
     59.50410992],
   [ 51.89656984,  52.18725649,  52.57764233,  54.39502415,
     55.61672911,  57.04180061,  58.54357871,  59.76354498,
     60.24155861,  60.59473182,  60.65985503,  60.92762915,
     60.76726905,  60.47166256,  60.42044548,  60.04043031,
     60.06031171],
   [ 51.69698671,  52.39494994,  52.71685017,  53.65488505,
     54.52480831,  56.33091376,  57.87811829,  58.36719736,
     59.31479758,  59.61329074,  59.81807224,  59.44053305,
     59.25522337,  59.5309563 ,  59.68850776,  59.54046914,
     58.60604327],
   [ 50.81523448,  51.5690217 ,  51.81382216,  52.88514118,
     53.27394887,  54.6941369 ,  55.81938471,  56.85401174,
     57.10874072,  58.55074569,  58.45869901,  57.67496274,
     57.3895956 ,  58.05319653,  58.83009123,  57.90678384,
     56.97717781],
   [ 49.61355365,  49.92298625,  50.56281781,  51.22117266,
     51.98020374,  53.0328832 ,  53.76602714,  54.94396421,
     55.16849545,  55.83033544,  56.19720112,  56.9382048 ,
     57.20669361,  56.76351885,  56.93632305,  56.16428665,  54.7570241 ],
   [ 49.17250426,  49.14663096,  49.86504335,  50.24394193,
     50.84671744,  51.21785439,  51.72667942,  52.8287256 ,
     53.65550669,  53.81801262,  54.62490542,  54.88045696,
     55.27367041,  54.89234901,  54.51005786,  53.57284022,
     52.53966996],
   [ 48.55125023,  48.99467099,  49.80237362,  49.67943854,
     49.45569362,  49.3387854 ,  50.129718  ,  49.94784906,
     51.03357894,  51.73021167,  52.0211617 ,  52.55805334,
     52.22956095,  51.88844202,  50.87410618,  50.39506101,
     49.72117909],
   [ 48.37551433,  48.30812683,  48.45300884,  48.50818535,
     47.76798967,  47.21965588,  47.60764424,  48.21327283,
     48.52370448,  49.95221655,  49.7608777 ,  50.1178807 ,
     50.15020093,  49.4369175 ,  49.16839811,  49.31254753,
     48.03208233],
   [ 46.91675497,  46.45280928,  46.37122283,  46.69881125,
     45.95493853,  46.33296801,  46.15091804,  46.09862998,
     46.31676066,  46.6199912 ,  47.60040926,  48.34096053,
     47.78005438,  48.0951173 ,  48.15291404,  47.21140107,
     46.28884057]])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rather than using a stock cmap, I will walk thorough the production of your own.

As you have already spotted, in order to have absolute control of the colors (without passing a colors array) when using cmaps, the number of colors in a cmap should be equal to the number of levels - 1.

We can easily demonstrate this with the following example. Lets make a colormap with the three primary colors in:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy


data = numpy.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)

cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap([(0, 0, 1), 
                               (0, 1, 0), 
                               (1, 0, 0)])
```

However, when we come to use this with anything other than 3+1 levels, we will get results that you may not expect:

```
plt.subplot(121)
plt.contourf(data, cmap=cmap, levels=[1, 4, 8, 10])

plt.subplot(122)
plt.contourf(data, cmap=cmap, levels=[1, 4, 8])

plt.show()
```

[image]

So I have shown that your levels must be of length `n_colors-1`, but because we want to have 3 colors, and the middle color always shown, we must also have an even number of levels.

Good, now we have some ground rules, lets make a LinearSegmentedColormap which is essentially just a ListedColormap with interpolation to N colors:

```
levs = range(12)
assert len(levs) % 2 == 0, 'N levels must be even.'

cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(name='red_white_blue', 
                                                 colors =[(0, 0, 1), 
                                                          (1, 1., 1), 
                                                          (1, 0, 0)],
                                                 N=len(levs)-1,
                                                 )
plt.contourf(data, cmap=cmap, levels=levs)
plt.show()
```

[image]

We can verify that the normailzed cmap has white as the middle color programatically:

```
>>> print cmap(0.5)
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

Hopefully this will give you all the information you need to be able to make any colormap you like and to use it successfully in contouring.

Comment: thanks! This really helps. Will create my own colormap from this introduction.